# UiWebView How to load local html in a state where there is no network

Tags: uiwebview

novice help, listen to people say `UiWebView` can load a local `html` file, I have a web application `html + js` can be run from a web page and want to run into the `ipad`.

if anyone knows, please express specific operation. Extremely grateful stackoverflow first post.

Answer (score 7):

Create a new Xcode project.
Import your html, javascript, css, etc, file(s) to your Xcode Project, [image: Add file(s) to Xcode Project]

[image: Select your html, javascript, css, image, etc file(s)]

Add UIWebView to your XIB, or storyboard. (As for me, I named it as webView - see figure)
[image: Add UIWebView and link and name it as you wish]

Then in the UIViewController delegate method `- (void)viewDidLoad`

> - `-`(void)viewDidLoad {
>     }

Put something like this:

> 

```
NSURL *rootURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"index" withExtension:@"html"];
    NSURLRequest *requestURL = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:rootURL];
    [self.webView loadRequest:requestURL];
```

Run your project to test. As for me, this is the result:[image: Ran on iPhone Simulator]

Comment: Thank you this will help a lot in implementing `UIWebView`.

Comment: How will this be done on **`Swift`**? Specifically on `Swift 5`?

Comment: @LeonAlexisCardinal This post is really outdated, and if you're using Swift 5 and your minimum target is like iOS 8, you might better use `WKWebView` instead. Please see [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview)'s documentation: